# Swift2でRealmのデータベースをどこに置けばいいのですか？（iOSの場合）

Tags: swift, realm

OSXの場合

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
let realmPath = (paths[0] as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.realm")
```

で指定できるが、iOSの場合標準はどこになるのですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

アプリケーションが使うディレクトリ構成は少し減っているだけでOS Xとほぼ変わりません。
その中でも特にiOSでは`Documents`ディレクトリか、`Library/Caches/`ディレクトリを使います。

プログラムから指定する方法もOS Xと同じです。

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
// => Documents/

NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
// => Librery/Cashes
```

`Documents`ディレクトリは標準でiCloudバックアップの対象になり、`Library/Caches/`ディレクトリはそうではないなどの違いがあります。

詳しくはアップルのリファレンスをご覧ください。

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW17

Comment: 詳しい説明、ありがとうございます。